# Function Pointer of an Operator in C++

Tags: c++, operators, function-pointers

So I have a function that expects a function pointer as an input and whose prototype goes something like this:

```
int function(int (*op)(int, int));
```

I was wondering if I can pass an operator in for that function pointer. Specifically this **built in** operator:

```
int operator|(int, int);
```

I've tried this:

```
function(&(operator|));
```

and got this kind of error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'function(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

I've tried this:

```
function(&(operator|(int, int)));
```

and got this kind of error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
```

I've looked for this situation in documentation, but I get things about the "address of" operator (operator&) instead of things about the address of an operator....

Edit:

See previous question
[Calling primitive operator-functions explicitly in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061162/calling-primitive-operator-functions-explicitly-in-c)

Comment: Does eliminating `&` in function call work?

Comment: @SuvP Why should it?  The function doesn't exist, so you can't take its address.

Comment: @JamesKanze I thought he overloaded it.

Comment: @SuvP He can't.  You can't overload an operator unless at least one of the operands is a user defined type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in operator | that takes two `int` and returns an `int` can not be accessed through the notation `operator|`. For instance, the following does not compile

```
int a = operator|(2,3);
```

Comment: That's because the function doesn't exist.  Built in operators are not functions, even if they behave as if they were for overload resolution.

Comment: So, basically, I need to create a function wrapper... int OR(int a, int b){return a|b;}

Comment: @Ned: Right, that will work. With C++11 you could also replace the function pointer by `std::function<int(int,int)>` and pass a lambda expression.

Comment: @user763305 Once turned into a `std::function`, it would also be possible to use `std::bit_or`

Comment: @Ned don't call it `OR` -- all caps indicates a macro traditionally.  Don't call it `or`, that is mapped to `||`.

Answer (score 5):

Because operators aren't available as functions, the standard provides a series of functors corresponding to operators. The most well known of these is `std::less` which is the default template parameter for ordering sorts, sets, and maps.

The full list can be found in the `functional` header. The one closest to your requirements is [`std::bit_or`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bit_or).

Unfortunately these are implemented as template classes with `operator()` rather than functions, so they won't be suitable for your specific use case. They're more suited for templates.