# Where is encapsulated the operators between integers?

Tags: c++, operators, encapsulation

I need to group some operators to be able to call them by index and to do that I need to know where they belong.

When `1 + 1` is executed there is clearly an `operator+(int, int)` which must belong to a class that has some relation with ints -maybe a template parameter?-

I tried accessing such function with `functional` header file included using `int::operator+` with no luck.

If something like

```
[
    the_class_i_need::operator+,
    the_class_i_need::operator-,
    ...
]
```

could be achieved or something alike, that'd perfect.

Comment: As ints are primitive types, I don't think there is a class definition.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6211435/6313992

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061162/calling-primitive-operator-functions-explicitly-in-c

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Not possible _"When an operator appears in an expression, and at least one of its operands has a __class type or an enumeration type__, then overload resolution is used to determine..."_ see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators  `int` is not a class or an enumeration.

Comment: "there is clearly an `operator+(int, int)` which must belong to a class that has some relation with ints" is wrong. There is no such `operator+(int, int)` function. Adding two `int`s using the `+` operator is a fundamental part of the language, not a function.